# How Kafka Nodes communicate with each other?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I could not find any details on Kafka nodes within a cluster communicate with each other. I mean during replication producer is going to contact with one of the node. Lets say it is the leader. Now for replication, that data should be copied to other nodes too as per configuration. So how that happens? Does those communication happen through zookeeper cluster? Or, Leader directly talks with Follower for replication? If they communicate directly, on which port they did that?

Comment: Check out this blog post from Confluent (there are many more about Kafka, too): https://www.confluent.io/blog/hands-free-kafka-replication-a-lesson-in-operational-simplicity/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Producers send messages to the Kafka leader with the other Kafka nodes acting as clients to this leader for replication, as any external Kafka client. The followers use to communicate with the leader the same port exposed for normal clients, by default 9092.